# Difference between server connection and server instance?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I was using MySQL Workbench and I am not able to figure out the difference between the following:

```
   1. Server instance
   2. Connection to server
```

In general I want to know if we can use `Open Connection to start querying` without creating
a server instance of the connection we are trying to connect. Are these two things independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one or two connections depending on what you wanna do with your server. For MySQL work (i.e. running queries) you need a MySQL connection. For server work (e.g. shutting the MySQL server down or manage other aspects that require shell access) you need a second connection (which is called a Server Instance).

Beginning with MySQL Workbench 6.0 we merged both connection settings into one interface.